# Why does "git push" on local branch result in merge with "develop" and push to "master" branch?

Tags: git, github, merge

The steps I took:
I cloned a repo from github.
I checked out a branch called "develop".
I created a new branch called "hotfix".
I worked on my local "hotfix" branch.
Then I tried to push "hotfix" to github.
I typed "git push".

The problem:
"hotfix" branch never showed up on github.

The result was as follows:
On github, it showed that "hotfix" was merged with "develop" and pushed to "master" branch.

Has anyone had a similar issue? Maybe there was an issue when I cloned?

I have since pushed my "hotfix" branch successfully by specifying "git push origin hotfix". Just wondering why "git push" would merge my local branch into develop, and then push to master.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the command line, I entered `git remote show origin`. It displays which branches are configured on remote/local for the `git push` command.

Answer (score 4):

When pushing new branches, you shoud use `git push hostname branchname`.

Comment: did you mean `git push <remote name> <branch name>` ? For example `git push github hotfix`

Comment: Thanks for your response. If you read the last few lines, you'll notice that I have already successfully pushed via "git push origin hotfix". My question is if anyone has run into a similar problem via "git push". Sometimes "git push" works just fine.

Comment: If I remember correctly, git push pushes the last branch you pushed to the last location you did it.

Comment: I see. I was assuming "git push" would get my current branch and push to my origin automatically. At any rate, I'll be sure to specify the branch on each future push.